# How do I cast an int to a long parameter?

Tags: java, parameters, casting, int

```
w = dogContainer.getWidth();
dogContainer.add(eyes((int)(.37*w, .39*w*1.75, w/4), eyeColor), 0);
```

I am getting an error trying to cast an Int to all these parameters, how do I correctly do it?

Comment: In java, sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Mabe `dogContainer.add( eyes( (int)(.37*w), (int)(.39*w*1.75), (int)(w/4) ), eyeColor, 0)`

Comment: Which version of Java do you have and what error are you getting?

Comment: The error is that it is trying to make me put an extra ";" after w/4);

Answer (score 0):

Please post the compile time error so it is easier for people to help you.

You do not need to cast an `int` to a `long` (notice use of lower case data types) - this will be take care-off by an underlying technique called conversion.

However if you are using `Integer` and `Long` (Upper case and full words) - these are wrapper class and the conversion will NOT happen automatically. You will need to do something like

```
Long myLong = myInteger.longValue();
```

Also as an additional observation (since the code is not posted I cannot be certain) - you are multiplying with a double `1.75` - if you perform operations that include a double the result will be a double even if some of the operands (like say `w`) is an int or a long (again something managed under the hod by conversion.

Comment: I am not sure why you posted the method invocation again. The megod definition of add and eyes would be useful if you have more questions.

Comment: Yes so change you arguments in your method to double from into. That's all.

Comment: No I cannot do your homework for you. Change your int to double everywhere and recompile.